# What, in detail, is a "value" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd love a very basic, descriptive definition, and specifically, answers to the following questions:

1. How is a value different than its representation as a literal?
2. Does a value get created, and continue to exist, regardless of whether it is stored? regardless of whether it continues to be used?
3. Is a value a state?

Comment: Are we being given a quiz, or are you taking one?

Comment: *sniff sniff* do I smell homework?

Comment: Value as in value expression of a DOM element? As in selector.val()? Value as in a variable? Anything can only continue to exist if it is stored, that would be axiomatic.

Comment: @giorgio & Paul: Interesting, I didn't read it that way. (I'm not saying you're wrong, just intrigued by the difference in perception.)

Comment: I'm reading a book, there will be no quiz, and while I am a student, I doubt that this will ever be homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting questions.

> 1) How is a value different than its representation as a literal?

The same way a chocolate cake is different from a recipe for chocolate cake. :-) Literals are a way of writing down the value that we want to use at that point in our program code. The value is what's actually held in memory when that code runs.

> 2) Does a value get created, and continue to exist, regardless of whether it is stored?

A value only exists if it's in memory, e.g., if it's in a simple variable or a property or on the stack.

> regardless of whether it continues to be used?

Values in memory may continue to exist for a while, until the garbage collector reclaims the memory they're in.

> 3) Is a value a state?

I may not be qualified to answer this, but conditionally I'll say "yes." If you have a simple variable and you put the value 1 in it, then later you put the value 2 in it, the value 1 is no longer there (or anywhere).

Note that values are not unique. You can have the value 1 in many places in memory at a time (and probably will).

Let's do a bit of a thought experiment:

```
var a = 42;
var b = a;
```

On the first line, we've got a literal that defines the value 42 (a number). We put it in a simple variable called `a`. So now we have 42 in `a`.

On the second line, we **copy** the value in `a` into `b`. Now we have two copies of the value 42, one in `a` and another in `b`. Suppose we then do this:

```
var c = b * 2;
```

The value is read from `b`, the value 2 is created from the literal, the JavaScript engine does the math, gets the value 84, and puts it in `c`.

Let's think about values that we're not using anymore:

```
function foo() {
    var o = {};
    o.p = 42;
    console.log(o.p);
}
foo();
```

When we call `foo`, we create an object and we remember where that object is in memory using a value we put in `o`. (That value is called an "object reference;" it tells the JavaScript engine where the object is. Unlike the number values earlier, the object isn't actually *in* `o`, the value saying where it is is in `o`.)

Now we do `o.p = 42`. So the value 42 is stored in a property called `p` on the object `o`, just like it was in our variable `a` earlier; properties are a bit like variables, but fancier.

We output the value, and then `foo` returns. `o`, the only variable that had a reference to the object we created, has gone away. So now the object is in memory, but none of our code knows where it is anymore (the JavaScript engine knows, but our code doesn't). Eventually, if it needs to free up the memory that object is consuming, the JavaScript engine will reclaim that memory and use it for something else, and the 42 that's in memory where the `p` property used to be will disappear.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder. I appreciate your help and your trust. Just trying to learn!